# Use Parse without push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, app-store-connect

I have an app that doesn't use push notifications. However, I'm using Parse for other reasons. When I submit my build I get the warning from iTunes that says:

> "Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement.  See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API."

Is there a way that I can silence this warning for future builds and not get the entitlements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're stuck with this warning, it is completely fine to just ignore it.